# How can the "Impossibly Simple Image Randomizer with jQuery" be accomplished.. without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to inject a random `background-image` into a div. I [came across](http://briancray.com/posts/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/) the following code which does this perfectly using the jQuery library:

**Sets the array of images:**

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
```

**Sets the div for the random background using previously defined array:**

```
$('#div').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

Here's the thing - I'd like to do this without having to load the jQuery library. I like the simplicity of the above code, but I'm new to the Javascript language and I don't know to reformat this for use without jQuery.

I've spent some time looking for Javascript alternatives to the above code, but they're all relatively lengthy or unnecessarily "busy". Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need this for one and only one typical brand of browser including the specific versionnumber?

Comment: I'd like if it worked across all the major browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in plain JS easily as well:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#div');
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + 
   images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')';
```

Comment: sorry.. didn't see it's not breaking the text

Comment: @elclanrs Thank you for the prompt answer, this works very well.

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that this will work on IE8+. If you need IE6,7 look for `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

a plain javascript code may be

`document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/'+images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]+')';`

Answer (score 0):

The reason jQuery is so popular is because it allows for the creation of such clear & concise coding across all platforms & browsers. So if you truly intend to recreate that level of cleanness in pure JavaScript… I doubt that would be possible. I might suggest that you try & recreate it as a project to teach yourself JavaScript, but I doubt anyone can come up with a cleaner solution that using jQuery as the foundation.